# Including non-modularised D3 library extension through webpack

Tags: d3.js, webpack, webpack-2, commonjs

I'm working on a project using webpack. I am successfully using the D3 npm package, using the following code to make it available:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

I would like to use another npm package that depends on d3 and makes drawing pie charts easier (https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3.chart.pie).

This package does not appear to be using any type of module syntax, it's just an anonymous function. What is the best way for me to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You need [`imports-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader):

```
import 'imports-loader?d3=d3!d3.chart.pie'
```

will basically write `var d3 = require('d3')` in front of the code of `d3.chart.pie` as it loads it. From then on you can use the package as part of `d3` itself.

If you don't want to import packages with the loader syntax in your .js files, you can create an alias for `d3.chart.pie` in your `webpack.config.js`